# How to resize base64 encoded image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I want resize **base64 encoded image** in python.I searched I could not find. I used **Pillow** package to do it. However, Pillow has no such kind of feature .

Comment: I don't think there is a single one library which would operate over base64 encoded images. Convert from base64, resize, convert to base64.

Answer (score 7):

This code does the job (Python 3):

```
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image

base64_str = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

buffer = io.BytesIO()
imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64_str)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
new_img = img.resize((2, 2))  # x, y
new_img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
img_b64 = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
print(str(img_b64)[2:-1])
```

EDIT: Reducing the size of a base64 image does not imply reducing the file size.